# Pandas pd.Series() and pd.DataFrame() are very slow

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help to improve the performance of the following code.

```
        for object in dict_of_objects.values():
            test = pd.Series(object.properties)    #properties is a dict
            series_list.append(test)

        # List comprehension is not really faster than the loop since pd.Series() takes most time
        #series_list = [pd.Series(object.properties) for object in dict_of_objects.values()]

        # Also very slow
        df = pd.DataFrame(series_list)
```

After timing the code a bit I found out that `pd.Series(object.properties)` and `pd.DataFrame(series_list)` are very slow - both need around 9s to complete while append needs only 0.4s. As a result, the list comprehension isn't really an improvement since it calls pd.Series(object.properties) as well.

Do you have some suggestions on how to improve the performance of this?

Best, Julz

Comment: How many items does `dict_of_objects` has?

Comment: try to iterate over dict with items() iterator, as @koPytok has mentioned.

Comment: @luis.parravicini: Usually some hundrets - but in this case about 50k. Thats when I found out it's so slow ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at some code snippets:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from copy import deepcopy as cp

N_objects = 10
N_samples = 10000

class SimpleClass:
    def __init__(self,prop):
        self.properties = prop

dict_of_objects = {'obj{}'.format(i): 
                        SimpleClass({
                                        'alice' : np.random.rand(N_samples),
                                        'bob'   : np.random.rand(N_samples)
                                    }) for i in range(N_objects)}

def slow_update(dict_of_objects):
    series_list = []
    for obj in dict_of_objects.values():
        test = pd.Series(obj.properties)
        series_list.append(test)
    return pd.DataFrame(series_list)

def med_update(dict_of_objects):
    return pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(obj.properties) for obj in dict_of_objects.values()])

def fast_update(dict_of_objects):
    keys = iter(dict_of_objects.values()).__next__().properties.keys()
    return pd.DataFrame({k: [obj.properties[k] for obj in dict_of_objects.values()] for k in keys})
```

And with timings:

```
>>> %timeit slow_update(dict_of_objects)
2.88 ms ± 19.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>>> %timeit med_update(dict_of_objects)
2.86 ms ± 23.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
>>> %timeit fast_update(dict_of_objects)
344 µs ± 17.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The fast update does the following:

1. Grab the fields from an iterator with one use of `__next__`.
2. Construct the fields using list comprehension.
3. Construct the data structure using dictionary comprehension.

It's about 8 times faster than most methods.

**Edit:** as correctly pointed out by @koPytok, `fast_update` will not work if each object's `properties` attribute has *different keys*. This is worth bearing in mind if you choose to implement this for something such as a NoSQL database grab -- in MongoDB, documents are not required to share the same fields (here swap document for object, field for key).

Enjoy!

Comment: Nice work! I've thought about algorithm similar to `fast_update` too. However, assuming that properties may have different keys, it won't work as expected. One needs to loop over all properties to collect all the keys

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this as well.

Comment: @koPytok: The properties-dict contains always the same keys - some of the values are just set to '' or np.nan if not needed.

Comment: @koPytok: Thanks! Indeed, if properties has different keys for each object, then `fast_update` won't work. Edited to note this.

Comment: Worked well, thank you. In fact, it's much more than 8 times faster (300ms instead of ~13-15s)

Answer (score 2):

The same result can be achieved, for example, like below:

```
properties_list = [o.properties for o in dict_of_objects.values()]
df = pd.DataFrame(properties_list).T
```

Or with `dict()` of properties, which requires less operations:

```
properties_dict = {k: o.properties for k, o in dict_of_objects.items()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(properties_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and give feedback.